# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord one row at a time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm running a query that selects many rows. When I loop over the results, I want to fetch a single row at a time (since it's too much memory to fetch them all at once).

Problem is, CodeIgniter's Active Record $query->row for all it's variations will fetch all the records from the database into the memory (and return a single row). I looked into the source of DB_result.php and found:

```
public function row_object($n = 0)
{
    $result = $this->result_object();
    if (count($result) == 0)
    {
        return $result;
    }

    if ($n != $this->current_row AND isset($result[$n]))
    {
        $this->current_row = $n;
    }

    return $result[$this->current_row];
}
```

and inside result_object():

```
...
while ($row = $this->_fetch_assoc())
{
    $this->result_array[] = $row;
}
```

This fetches ALL of the records from the database into the memory.

Is there a workaround that will allow me to fetch a single row without loading the entire resultset into the memory?

Comment: You seem so well researched I suppose you've already considered this, but why not use just raw SQL with LIMIT to select one row at a time?

Comment: adding $i with a number in inside_result_object? And  $this->result_array[$i] so you can point to a specific row?

Comment: @Calle this is a very bad solution, it would mean running over 100,000 queries

Comment: @edwardmp it works the same

Comment: @galchen Yes, it sucks but I thought that's what you wanted to do...? What _do you mean_ by fetching one row at a time?

Comment: just like in plain mysql, fetch a single row from the result set

Comment: I still don't get your question. You cannot select one at a time and at the same time not select one at a time...

Comment: I want to select all of the rows and fetch one row at a time. You see, when you run an SQL query, the MySQL engine generates a result set. You have a pointer for the current position. You can run over the results and fetch data (inside the MySQL service). When you $query->reuslt(), it returns the ENTIRE result set to PHP...

Comment: But that's just like fetching a result array and then looping over it? Isn't this what you couldn't do because of memory constraint?

Comment: exactly, returning all of the results to the PHP will use a lot of memory

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

```
$query = $this->db->get();
while($r = $query->_fetch_object()){
    ...
}
```

probably the reason they left it public...