# Loop through query results without loading them all in array in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

I'm failing to find a specific statement if it is possible to use Codeigniter DB API to batch process all records in a table (thousands of them potentially) without loading all results in a results array which leads to poor resource (memory) management and related issues.

I've found several discussions, but it's hard for me to draw a clear conclusion.

I'm tempted to go with plain mysql_query, but it just doesn't look right.

Please help.

Thanks

v.

EDIT:
(from CI DB_REsult.php):

```
while ($row = $this->_fetch_object())
    {
        $object = new $class_name();

        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {
            $object->$key = $value;
        }

        $result_object[] = $object; //I'm trying to avoid this. It is ridiculous with thousands of results.
    }
```

Comment: codeigniter's DB API which is active record is just a query builder, using it and using a plain query is just the same.

Comment: @tomexsans thanks, but how do I run the query and access results one at a time, just like I would do with e.g. mysql_fetch_object or mysql_fetch_assoc? as soon as I call ci result() I'm stuck with an array of zillion results.

Comment: `$this->db->query();` executes the query `result()` fetches as object and `result_array()` fetches array

Comment: but the accent here is on fetch, not the way the row is represented. personally I don't care if I get rows as arrays or objects. I just want to avoid array of all results.

Comment: then you have to limit your query for every process. like 50 a time

Comment: thanks again. so the only way is to execute a bunch of queries, and deal with one chunk of results at a time.

Comment: if you limit your results instead of dealing or processing a thousand results you only process small amounts at a time. What is the matter with that than loading all result?

Comment: And a similar answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500110/codeigniter-activerecord-one-row-at-a-time

Comment: Yes. I agree it is a duplicate. Still hate the private intent of _fetch_object function :)